# How to add Image dynamically in a button with slide show?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a scenario where I have to make a button with slide show, I have tried alot but unable to make a slide show.

```
Image img = new Image();
            string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "chart2 - Copy.png";
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

            StackPanel stackPnl = new StackPanel();
            stackPnl.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            stackPnl.Margin = new Thickness(10);
            stackPnl.Children.Add(img);

            button1.Content = stackPnl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing in MVVM will be easy. 
I am giving an idea or a mock how to execute it.

### XAML

```
  <Button Height="200" Width="200">
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Image>
               <Image.Source>
                   <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageURI}" />
               </Image.Source>
            </image>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button>
```

### VM

```
private string _ImageURI = "";// add the path of your image in the quotes
        public string ImageURI { get { return _ImageURI; } set { _ImageURI = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

    public void SlideShow()
    {
        DispatcherTimer DT = new DispatcherTimer();
        DT.Tick += DT_Tick;
        DT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        DT.Start();
    }

    private void DT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change your image uri here 'ImageURI'
    }
```

Call `SlideShow()` in your `VM constructor` or where ever you want.

Comment: Thanx I got it. I ll do it now